# MVC Cache Issue (Possibly) - Object Appears Sporadically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

All:

We are using MVC 4.0 and I am having a heck of a time figuring out what is causing this.

I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginAccordionPanel("Cancelled Reason", "pnlCancelledReason"))
   {
       @Html.Partial("~/Views/Project_View/Tracking/_CancelledReason.cshtml", Model) 
   }
```

If I navigate to the page to show the above code, my panel (and objects inside) do not appear.  But if I append any HTML and refresh the page, all of a sudden, the objects appear.  If I stop debugging, start it up again and navigate to the page, the above no longer appears but if I remove the added HTML, the objects then appear again.

I found a few articles about all the various places to clear .Net caches and VS caches, I am still experiencing this issue.

I also added 
    `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]`
to my ActionResult and still experiencing the issue.

There are about 10 total sections on this page using code very simliar to the above (just changing the titles and path to the view).  They all work with no problems, except the one I am asking about.

When I say "...append any HTML...", this is what I mean:

`@using (Html.BeginAccordionPanel("Cancelled Reason", "pnlCancelledReason"))
   {
       @Html.Partial("~/Views/Project_View/Tracking/_CancelledReason.cshtml", Model) <b></b>
   }`

As you see in this example, all I did was add some HTML to the end, and the panel will then appear until I stop / start again.

Something I noticed in playing around, when I run in DEBUG mode, the yellow line that shows the line you are on, seems to not highlight the entire @Html.Partial line, but stops about 80% of the way across the line, but doesn't do this with any other line on the view until I do something like above (append HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending two days on this and not sure why, but it seems if I remove the “.generated.cs” file from Visual Studio this issue goes away.  I didn’t find any articles for this, just figured ‘why the heck not’.

Sorry to have bothered you.